# Literal.ToString() vs Literal.Text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know about `Literal.ToString()` and `Literal.Text` property. Whether both functionality are same or not. In a project, both are used.

I searched for some article and I didn't get clear information on it. Can anyone give details in brief with some example?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: What is Literal.Text?

Comment: One of the `Literal` control Property

Comment: Are you talking about asp.net Libteral control????

Comment: So you should have tagged your question with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Text` is a property.

`ToString()` is a method.

To set the content of a Literal you'd you the Text property `Literal.Text = "text"`

`ToString()` will return text that represents the literal object.

If you want to get the text of a literal you'd use `string str = Literal.Text` adding `ToString()` to that would be redundant because the text property is a string.

Comment: Can we use both to retrieve the content? Both will return the same content?

Comment: to retrieve the content, use the property. `string str = Literal.Text` to set the content would be the opposite `Literal.Text="mytext";`

Comment: @Jesuraja see my answer. It seems like everyone who is commenting here has absolutely no skill in comprehending your question.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan good job, basically saying the same thing as in my answer except adding overriding like he/she is going to understand the override modifier when he/she is just still learning the difference between properties and methods.

Comment: @prospector Good point, sorry. However, I bring up one clear point that you do not, and that is what ToString returns. I think that "Text that represents the literal object" sounds cryptic to anyone. Either way I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing the Type of Literal. my guess is that the implementation of ToString() method returns it Text so you can use both.

Answer (score 0):

`Text` is a `Property` allows to *Get* or *Set* the Caption in `Literal` control.

`ToString()` is a `method` to *return* (*Get*) the string representation of the current object (`Literal`).

Answer (score 0):

`ToString()` on this control will return the qualified name of the control, in this case `"System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal"`.

It is possible to override `ToString()` to return the `Text` property of the Literal control.

```
public class MyCustomLiteral : Literal
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Text;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
literal1.Text = "Hi";
Console.Write(literal1.ToString());
//Hi
```

If you dig into the source code for `Object.ToString()` you will find the following

```
// Returns a String which represents the object instance.  The default
// for an object is to return the fully qualified name of the class.
public virtual String ToString()
{ 
    return GetType().ToString(); 
}
```